# get_cat_ID() for wp_create_category()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, categories

I created a plugin which create new `category`,
when new `custom post type` created:

```
static function add_new_category_when_new_box_created($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    if (get_post_type() == POSTTYPE) {
        //only new box creates category no updated one
        if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id))
            return false;

        $post_title = $post->post_title;
        if (!empty($post_title) && empty(get_cat_ID($post_title))) {
            wp_create_category($post_title);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then when I want to use `get_cat_ID()` for any of categories created by above function, it returns `0`.